# Strange "Invalid column name" error when executing SP

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

We have an SP in which we build a query and then execute the query by using the `exec(@select)` call, where the variable that holds the SQL query as it is constructed is `@select`.

I have been assigned a request to add a new column to the resultset returned by the SP. This new column should not be returned in all circumstances, but only under a certain condition. Naturally, I added the following code to the SP.

```
IF @conditionIsMet
BEGIN
set @select =  @select + ", 'compQty' = convert(varchar(53), di.qty) "
END
```

This worked fine until today, when my app keeps throwing a SQL exception with the message, "Invalid column name: compQty". This is erratic and the exception is not thrown always.

Executing the SP in SQL Server Management Studio gives no errors. The column is rendered with the heading 'compQty'. So the app *should* pick up the column, but it doesn't seem to!!

Can some one help?

Comment: log the value of @Select, compare the "it worked" to the "it failed" and see if there is a pattern

Comment: @KM, when it fails, I run the SP in Management Studio and I can see the compQty column. It appears that resultSet.getString("compQty") does not see the compQty column.

Comment: Have you tried fully specifying the column i.e. tablename.compQty ? Also, instead of using quotes it's better to use square brackets i.e. [tablename].[compQty] .

Answer (score 1):

Don't surround the column name in single quotes `'compQty`'

Comment: @Mitch, I did try this, and it worked for a while, but the issue is back again. :-(. Also, there are other fields before this, that do have single quotes. There doesn't seem to be a problem with those.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the Quoted Identifier problem that @Tapori identified: if the stored proc looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Something]
AS
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

   DECLARE @select NVARCHAR(200)

   SET @select = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ''col1'' = 42'
GO
```

Then you'll have a problem. The issue is that the setting of QUOTED_IDENTIFIER doesn't matter when the stored proc is executed, it matters when the stored proc is **created**. So you actually need to do:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Something]
AS
   DECLARE @select NVARCHAR(200)

   SET @select = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ''col1'' = 42'
GO
```

And see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like Quoted Identifiers is the issue here.

It seems like a setting was changed in your environment for the quoted identifiers and that caused the exception. Use this at the beginning of your query:

Set Quoted_Identifier OFF;

Edit: You are sometimes thrown the issue and sometimes not because your IF condition is not always met.

Comment: @Tapori, we do have set ANSI_NULLS ON and set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF at the start of our SP.

Comment: @Tapori, our flow is that the SP will be executed twice - the first time, the condition is not met, and the second time, the condition IS met. So if it is failing because of the IF, it should fail everytime. But not so here - it failed first time, then I removed the quotes around the column name as @Mitch suggested, and it worked, and now is failing again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same table in more than one schema you may face the

> Invalid column name

Solution: explicit definition of schema: `[schemaName].[tableName]`